# Dynamically determine Component to render at runtime

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code in a ReactComponent class:

```
render() {
    const snippets = entity.snippets.map(
        function (snippet, props) {
            const SnippetType = snippet['type'];
            //const SnippetType = "Text";
            return <SnippetType key={Math.random()} />;
        }
    );
// .......
    return (
        <article>
            {snippets};
        </article>
    )
}
```

The Text Component looks like this.

```
const Text = (props) => (
    <div className="snippet text-snippet">
        <h2>{props.name}</h2>
        <p>{props.content}</p>
    </div>
);
```

I'm not sure, what I'm doing wrong here, but `<SnippetName ...>` always renders HTML like  instead of the actual Component, even if I define `Text`  manually as a string (as per the commented line above).

After several hours of failing, I ask you: What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you storing in the `snippet` variable? If you store the results of loading a component (ie `const snippet['type'] = require('MyTextComponent')`), then this should work.

Rendering a string as a component doesn't work because a string isn't a component. Compare what a variable looks like when you set it to a component vs a string and you'll see what I mean (ie for your commented out `//const SnippetType = "Text";`.

Maybe try something like

```
const SnippetComponents = {};
SnippetComponents['text'] = require('MyTextComponent');
```

then you can go

```
const Snippet = SnippetComponents['text']
<Snippet someProps={stuff}/>
```

Comment: It's working now. Thanks! I never realized that I have to use the actual function tu make it work.